# Monaco editor how to set a certain words to be clickable with call back handler

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a requirement to show java code in the monaco editor, what I need to do:

1. I need to highlights certain words;
2. I want to make highlighted words to be clickable and add event handler to these words.

I searched online and knows how to highlight the words using  editor.deltaDecorations, but I really have no idea how to add event handler to those highlighted words.

Also we are now using ngx-monaco-editor, an angular wrapper for monaco, any solution to provide highlights and click handling for this component?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot attach a mouse handler to the highlighted words, but you can do so for the editor itself.

A possible approach would be to attach handlers to [onMouseDown](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#onmousedown) and [onMouseUp](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#onmouseup). When the mouse-down event arrives use [getWordAtPosition](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#getwordatposition) and check if that is one of special words. If so, store it somewhere. In mouseUp do the same and compare the stored word with what you found in the up event. If they are the same do your actual click handling.

Comment: This solution seemed wrokable. but now I am using ngx-monaco-editor, which is a angular wrapper for monaco, I wondered if there is solution to make it work for highlights, thanks

Comment: The idea I presented above is wrapper agnostic. You will always be able to attach mouse handlers, be it in native monaco, react-monaco or angular-monaco.

Comment: Is this how vscode does make the links here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fARQ7.png

Comment: I haven't looked up how VS Code does it, but you can do yourself in their Github repository.